# Como mostrar/exibir uma lista de strings em Lista encadeada?

Tags: c, string, lista

Galera, comecei agora a aprender Lista Encadeada na linguagem C. Por que meu código não exibi string inteira na tela? Está exibindo apenas inteiros ou 1 caractere.
O problema está na parte de exibir (o erro deve estar a partir da linha 63 do programa abaixo) o qual não mostra strings. 
Esse é o modelo que o professor está ensinando. Se alguém puder dar uma verificada e me ajudar a encontrar a fórmula de imprimir a lista de alunos (strings) corretamente agradeço muito a ajuda.. tmj  S2

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


typedef struct Alunos {
    char informacao;
    struct Alunos *proximo;
}Aluno;

int main ()
{
    Aluno* Lista;
    int opcao=0;
    void IniciarLista(Aluno **pRecebido);
    void InserirElemento(Aluno **pRecebido);
    void BuscarElemento(Aluno **pRecebido);
    void RemoverElemento(Aluno **pRecebido);
    int leValor(int *valorRecebido);
    Lista = (Aluno*)malloc(sizeof(Aluno));
    IniciarLista(&Lista);

    for(;;) {
        printf("\nDigite 1 para inserir aluno: ");
        printf("\nDigite 2 para consultar alunos inseridos: ");
        printf("\nDigite 3 para remover aluno: ");
        printf("\nDigite 4 para Sair!\n\n");
        scanf("%d", &opcao);
        opcao = leValor(&opcao);
        switch(opcao) {
            case 1:
                InserirElemento(&Lista);
                break;
            case 2:
                BuscarElemento(&Lista);
                break;
            case 3:
                RemoverElemento(&Lista);
                break;
            case 4:
                exit(0);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void IniciarLista(Aluno **pRecebido) {
    (*pRecebido)->proximo=NULL;
}

void InserirElemento(Aluno **pRecebido) {
    Aluno *temporario;
    char nome1[50];
    printf("\nNome do aluno: ");
    scanf("%s", &nome1);
    temporario=(Aluno*)malloc(sizeof(Aluno));
    temporario->informacao = nome1[50];
    temporario->proximo=(*pRecebido)->proximo;
    (*pRecebido)->proximo=temporario;
}

void BuscarElemento (Aluno **pRecebido) {
    Aluno *temporario;
    if((*pRecebido)->proximo==NULL) {
        printf("\nLista vazia!\n");
    }else if (temporario!=NULL){
        temporario=(Aluno*)malloc(sizeof(Aluno));
        temporario=(*pRecebido)->proximo;
         {
            printf("\nAluno: %s\n", temporario->informacao);
            temporario=temporario->proximo;
        }
    }
}

void RemoverElemento (Aluno **pRecebido) {
    Aluno *temporario;
    if((*pRecebido)->proximo==NULL) {
        printf("\nLista Vazia!\n");
    }else {
        temporario=(*pRecebido)->proximo;
        (*pRecebido)->proximo=temporario->proximo;
        free(temporario);
    }
}

int leValor(int *valorRecebido) {
    while((*valorRecebido>4) || (*valorRecebido<1)) {
        printf("\nOpcao invalida. Tente novamente:\n");
        scanf("%d", &(*valorRecebido));
    }
    return(*valorRecebido);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

O resultado está printando 1 caracter porque a sua estrutura esta  `char informacao` que significa apenas 1 caracter e não `char* informacao` ou `char informacao[100]` que significa "string"

Você também esta alocando um novo aluno a variável `temporario` fazendo com que o resultado printado seja errado.

Normalmente quando criamos uma lista encadeada chamamos o primeiro elemento de head e não lista.

Não é necessário utilizar ponteiros duplos para passar o `Lista` (head) para as funções.

```
void IniciarLista(Aluno *pRecebido);
void InserirElemento(Aluno *pRecebido);
void BuscarElemento(Aluno *pRecebido);
void RemoverElemento(Aluno *pRecebido);
...
case 1:
    InserirElemento(Lista);
    break;
case 2:
    BuscarElemento(Lista);
    break;
case 3:
    RemoverElemento(Lista);
    break;
```

Não é necessário fazer cast do malloc.

```
Lista = malloc(sizeof(Aluno));
```

A sua função `BuscarElemento` não parece estar buscando algo a sua intenção era printar toda a lista? Se for printar observe a mudança que fiz.

```
void BuscarElemento (Aluno *head) {
    if(head==NULL) {
        printf("\nLista vazia!\n");
    }else {
        int i = 0;
        Aluno *temporario = head; //Não aloca um novo Aluno
        while (temporario != NULL)
        {
            printf("Aluno[%d]: %c\n", i, temporario->informacao); //O tipo de dado é char!
            temporario = temporario->proximo;
            ++i;
        }
    }
}
```